# Starting a program with parameters containing quotes and spaces from batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Windows 7 x64.

This command works great if run at the command line.

```
TeamViewer_Assignment.exe -apitoken 123-XXX -datafile "C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\AssignmentData.json" -devicealias "Computer"
```

I would like to be able to run it using a batch file but have run into problems passing the parameters. This is what I've come up with and while it does run the `.exe` it doesn't pass in any of the parameters.

```
Start "" "%~dp0TeamViewer_Assignment.exe" "-apitoken 123-XXX" ""-datafile "C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\AssignmentData.json""" ""-devicealias "Computer"""
```

I've read over a ton of other SO questions, each with their own solutions and escaping characters, but have yet to make anything work.

Is there some simple thing that I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Wild guess, but I would assume you don't put quotes around the entire option for the program if at all.  I would test this without using the quotes `-apitoken 123-XXX` or just putting quotes around the value of the option: `-apitoken "123-XXX"` Do the same for the other options.

Comment: @Squashman You're correct.. Thanks a lot! This worked for me: `Start /WAIT "" "%~dp0TeamViewer_Assignment.exe" -apitoken 123-XXX -datafile "C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\AssignmentData.json" -devicealias "Computer"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was overthinking this... Thanks to @Squashman for helping me out.

```
Start /WAIT "" "%~dp0TeamViewer_Assignment.exe" -apitoken 123-XXX -datafile "C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\AssignmentData.json" -devicealias "Computer"
```